# Ruby on Rails - custom REST action and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made custom REST action called makedefault:

```
  class PicturesController < ApplicationController
    def makedefault
      ...
    end
  end
```

But I get No route matches [POST] "/pictures/12" error.

In routes I've tried:

```
get "/pictures/:id" => "pictures#show"
```

But it didn't help. How can I make my own REST action and route it properly?

Comment: Are you trying to make a POST route? Or a GET?

If you want to route users to your `makedefault` action, it should be `get "/pictures/:id" => "pictures#makedefault"` or `post "/pictures/:id" => "pictures#makedefault"`

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to create a POST route (this is what I understand from the question), you should try this:
`post "/pictures/:id" => "pictures#makedefault"`
The second argument after `#` must be pointed to your custom action.